# How to set up autoscaling for ECS cluster that uses scheduled tasks and no service?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, autoscaling

I have an ECS cluster which i have an ec2 instance tied to and a scheduled task set to run daily using the 'Scheduled Tasks' functionality on the ECS dashboard.

This task runs a a bunch of containers that are each relatively expensive in memory, and this is compounded even more so with all the containers running at once.

I do not currently have a service set up for the ECS cluster and it is my understanding that for my goals, running a set task on some interval, a service would not be used.

AWS's definition of a service in there ECS docs says:

```
An Amazon ECS service enables you to run and maintain a specified number of instances of a task definition simultaneously in an Amazon ECS cluster.
```

Since this is not what I want; instead i need to just run a task on some scheduled interval i gather i do not need an service tied to my ECS cluster.

My question is on how to set up autoscaling for my scheduled tasks? The only references i can find to auto scaling within an ECS cluster are to do with creating ecs services that auto scale - which again, is not what I want (at least from how i understand ecs services to work).

What I need is for my ec2 instances to auto scale with my scheduled task running, allocating more resources as need for the task to run. Would I just need to set up auto scaling on the specific ec2 instance the ecs cluster is tied to from within the ec2 dashboard or is there some other way to do this from ECS directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want; instead, I need to just run a task on some scheduled interval I gather I do not need a service tied to my ECS cluster.

For the above use case better to use **fargate** and **you will not maintain or worry about auto-scaling scheduling**, all you need to setup schedule task and AWS will take care of memory and other resources required for your task plus you will only **pay for the resources that were used by you ECS task**, unlike EC2 type task where you pay for the container instance.

> **AWS Fargate is a serverless compute engine for containers** that works with both Amazon Elastic Container Service (ECS) and Amazon Elastic Kubernetes Service (EKS). Fargate makes it easy for you to focus on building your applications. **Fargate removes the need to provision and manage servers, lets you specify and pay for resources per application**, and improves security through application isolation by design.

[aws fargate](https://aws.amazon.com/fargate/)

Create a cloud watch rule base on some schedule that will trigger the task, make sure that the container exit once it completes the job, fargate will automatically stop the container.

[image]

[image]

[cloudwatch-event-rule-to-invoke-an-ecs-task](https://medium.com/@dyuthi.pedaballi/configure-cloudwatch-event-rule-to-invoke-an-ecs-task-net-core-console-application-a60e04402b4f)

Comment: thank you @Adiii this was very helpful information. One thing i am a little confused by is if fargate takes care of all the resource management why when i create a fargate task am i asked to set a task size for the memory and cpu useage? Shouldnt it just scale up to what the task needs without me needing to specify this?

Comment: No, CPU and memory are required for task size. while my meant to say that fargate will reserve the specified memory and CPU etc for that task without worrying about backend instances

Comment: that makes sense. It seems like the most I can allocate in memory to my Fargate task in 30gb. Is there any common practice beyond just breaking up the task into seperate tasks that run subsets of all the containersi need run to get around this 30gb memory limit?

Comment: 30GB is the max memory that you can allocate,I will recommend to go with smaller one base on memory metrics after testing at dev/stage allocate accordingly for production, the main aim of fargate to save cost so better to go with configuration base on some metrics. where I prefer single container per task as at more control over notification, logs and other metrics plus for me it seems cost effective as it not necessary that all container will need such high CPU or memory so my preference is "One container per task"